# Accessing Onedrive For Business Files via REST api in something other than a .NET application?

Tags: rest, azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I apologize for my fundamental lack of knowledge in regards to these technologies in advance. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the whole Azure AD/Authentication process in general, and I don't feel that Microsoft's support documents adequately describe much of the process.

I appears to me that the REST requests themselves are quite simple, and the following page seems to detail them quite well. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations

However, what I fail to understand is the authentication process.

My goal here is to determine if what I'd like to do is even possible, so I will begin with that. What I need to be able to do is to be able to make REST API calls from a JSP or potentially a PHP script to access a link to a file located on a user's Onedrive for Business account. To put it simply, I would just like to be able to quickly get a publicly accessible link to a user's file. From the perspective of having access to the REST API, that seems to be a simple task, my challenge is understanding and implementing the capability to do so.

Correct me if I am wrong, but my current understanding of the process goes something like so.

1. Create an application in Azure AD, you need to define a location for signing on. I'm not certain how this works at all, does the defined location need to be making a request to sign on somehow? Does it need to exist on the same domain? I honestly have no idea the nature of how you actually go about signing in, but it requires some authentication of the application as well.
2. Once you have signed in, you have access to a 'security token' that has information about the application and what it can access. how is this token stored? A server session, browser cookies?
3. Somehow you pass this token along with your REST request and it is determined that you have access to the information you are requesting.

I have used pre-made JavaScript file pickers in the past to facilitate the selection of user files for things such as Google Drive and Dropbox, but it doesn't appear as though any such tools exist for Onedrive for Business, so I will need to become familiar with the authentication process myself. Looking into the Microsoft documentation has only served to confuse myself more, and unfortunately all of the examples are for .NET projects as far as I can tell. I am afraid that this means that is it only possible to access this information from a .NET project, but please correct me if this is not the case.

I realize that this question appears extremely ignorant, and that's likely because it is. Moving from JavaScript file pickers to something like this appears to be a significant leap in required technical prowess, and I'm still rather new, so please forgive my inexperience. Most importantly I'd like to know if what I'm looking to do is possible at all, and secondly if there are any readily available resources that are a little more focused than the Microsoft documentation.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great resources available for coding for Office 365 and not just those on MSDN.

The best place to start is http://dev.office.com.  This is the destination for information on O365 development.  You can get to the documentation, training materials and code samples.  The code samples have a filter so you can search on a number of properties including language and product.  There are samples of course for .net, but also for iOS, Android and PHP, which is what you mention you want to use for your project.

http://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2138

This sample connects to the calendar, but the important part is understanding the authentication process for your application to Azure AD.  Once you get the authentication working, you can call the other O365 services by getting the resource url to the appropriate resource from the Discovery Service.

If you need more samples, http://github.com/officedev is the place to look.  These samples are from Microsoft, the community as well as the code used in Microsoft and community training events and presentations.

If you prefer, some great training courses exist on Microsoft Virtual Academy for Office 365 development.  These are online videos that are broken into chapters and sections so you can easily find what you need.  They often have labs associated with them as well.  I recommend the Intro to Office 365 Development - Section 5 to get a quick overview of the Office 365 APIs and then look at the Deep Dive: Integrate Office 365 APIs in Your Web Apps.

If you still have questions, this is the place to post them. Hope this helps.  Reply if you have any questions.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your timely response. This is a lot to take in, so I will look into the training videos to get started and then see if I can find any helpful examples. I appreciate you taking the time to answer, this looks very promising. Once I've spent some more time researching I will get back to you about whether I've figured out a solution.